# Destroy previous activity when user logged in

Tags: java, android, xml

I am having two activities, login.java and home.java, The user Sign in with login.java, after successful login, the user will be redirected to home.java. If the user presses back button when he is in home activity, app is moving back to login activity. How to avoid redirecting back to Login page instead of closing the Application ?

Comment: I tried with getBaseContext and getApplicationContext while launching the home activity, i dont know whether i am going in a right way or not ? Kindly guide me.

Answer (score 0):

After starting the new activity call `finish()`
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finish()